# Using Pingfederate with .NET Core 2.0 or above

Tags: .net-core, pingfederate

I am researching how to use pingfederate authentication with .Net Core2 and I did not find much that would go with .NET Core 2. The only nuget package I found about this was Owin.Security.Providers.PingFederate I was wondering if there is a newer approach?